# double quote error when using ProcessStartInfo in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, string-interpolation, processstartinfo

I'm trying to open run a few arguments using cmd.exe from ProcessStartInfo in C#
but my folder navigation needs to include double quotes eg. "C:\this is\my\folder site"

as you see the reason for using double quotes is because the folders have space on their name.

this is my code

```
var ddd = "\"" + projectPath + "\"";
        var strCmdTxt = "/c  cd " + ddd + " && code .";

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = strCmdTxt, UseShellExecute = true, CreateNoWindow= true
        };
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

BUT, what it runs is something like this

cd\ "C:\this is\my\folder site\"

which, just returns me to C drive

The command should be **cd "C:\this is\my\folder site"**

Comment: Can you post the actual value of `projectPath` because I feel the problem is there.

Comment: Moment, i think there is a switch for "start directory", which have to be placed after `/C`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you're trying to achieve is start `VS Code` in the specified folder. Consider using the working directory of the process you're starting, instead of trying to navigate to that directory and starting `VS Code` in there. Here is a method to help with that:

```
private static void StartVSCodeInFolder(string projectPath)
{
    using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe",
            Arguments = ".",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = projectPath
        };
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not change the working directory using the Environment class and simply using "code.exe".

It seems like it would be a cleaner approach.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code";
```